# Get URL paramters and clean the url using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, iframe

Im creating a website that have 2 iframes, the first iframe have a song playing and the second one have the website. Here is my index.php file:

```
<?php
$base_url = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/site/';
?>
<iframe src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>music.php" frameborder="0" width="960px" height="1px"></iframe>

<?php
$page = $_GET['params'];

switch ($page) {
    case 'home':
        $page = 'home.php';
        break;
    case 'contact':
        $page = 'contact.php';
        break;
}
?>

<iframe src="<?php echo $base_url; ?><?php echo $page ?>" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

And this is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site/index.php?params=$1
```

It's working fine but what i need is:

When the user try to access http://www.mywebsite.com/contact
I need to get this 'contact' for my switch statement and clean the url to http://www.mywebsite.com

Simulation:

1. Request http://www.mywebsite.com/contact
2. Get param 'contact'
3. Load the contact.php file
4. Clean the url to http://www.mywebsite.com

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need step 4?

Comment: haha Sry, removed this step.

Comment: No prob, see my generic answer below, that should solve your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the first 3 steps with

```
RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact.php?params=contact [L,QSA]
```

if you add that before the rules that you already have. But you can't "clean" the URL to `http://www.mywebsite.com/`, since then it will be indistinguishable from `site/index.php?params=home`.

For any "contact" page, then:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILEMAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php?params=$1 [L,QSA]
```

You're also going to want to make sure `Multiviews` is turned off:

```
Options Multiviews
```

Comment: there are other urls beyond the contact, i removed it to make the code short. Btw i removed the 4 step from htaccess ! Sry for that

Answer (score 1):

You need just one generic rule like this:

```
# To internally forward /anything to /anything.php?params=anything
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php?params=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "clean the URL to http://www.mywebsite.com" ?

Because if you want to transmit the contact parameter you can use the QSA flag which appends query string (Query String Append) but if you just want to clean URL you can do some treatments in your contact.php and then redirect to main page with PHP header function.

He answered while I was typing my answer but I was about to give you Jon Lin's code

Comment: I'm doing this because today when the page 'http://www.mywebsite.com/contact' is requested it's working fine, but when the user click in 'home' link the website is redirected to home but the URL keeps http://www.mywebsite.com/contact ( because of the iframe )